# mount error(2): No such file or directory - CIFS - Rasperry Pi

Tags: mount, raspbian, cifs, smb

I am playing around with a share on my NAS being unable to mount a SMB share.
Based on the [ubuntu smb documentation](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Samba_Client_cifs/) the command for mounting a SMB / CIFS should be as following:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=test,password=pw1234 //<server>/home ~/test
```

The error message is:

```
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I already tried the following things:

- replaced ~/test with absolute path /home/pi/test - no change
- checked that /home/pi/test exists - the folder exists
- tried to mount the share using windows 7 (user + pw) - worked
- pinged the server - server is reachable
- checked smbclient for the share

  ```
  smbclient -U test -L //<server>
  WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
  Enter test's password:
  Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.4.16]

  Sharename       Type      Comment
  ---------       ----      -------
  ...
  home            Disk      Home directory of test
  Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.4.16]
  ```
- tried adding "vers=1.0", "vers=2.0", "vers=2.1", "vers=3.0" to -o flag

  ```
  sudo mount -t cifs -o username=test,password=pw1234,vers=1.0 //<server>/home /home/pi/test/
  mount error(2): No such file or directory
  Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
  ```
- tried adding "sec=ntlm" to -o flag

  ```
  sudo mount -t cifs -o username=test,password=pw1234,sec=ntlm //<server>/home /home/pi/test/
  mount error(22): Invalid argument
  Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
  ```
- tried the -v flag of mount

  ```
  sudo mount -v -t cifs -o username=test,password=pw1234 //<server>/home /home/pi/test/
  mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=<correct_ip>,unc=\\<server>\home,user=test,pass=********
  mount error(2): No such file or directory
  Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
  ```
- tried adding "nodfs" to -o flag
  [from this unix-stackexchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120677/can-not-use-mount-cifs-mount-error2-no-such-file-or-directory/259155?newreg=d3a5f90b8f5e4838854b0c5afbabdd73)
- read [can not use mount.cifs: mount error(2): No such file or directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120677/can-not-use-mount-cifs-mount-error2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Here the specs of the pi:

- uname -a : Linux  4.14.52-v7+ #1123 SMP Wed Jun 27 17:35:49 BST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: I have exactly the same issue on a Ubuntu 18.04 server in Azure, did you ever solve this or find a workaround?

Comment: @Ralph Unfortunately never found out why it was not working - at some point it magically started working.