# Cannot mount Synology server on Raspberry Pi, but can access it in the file browser (mount error(2): No such file or directory)

Tags: linux, mount, raspberry-pi, raspbian, cifs

I am trying to access the files on my NAS within programs and so I want to mount the network share.

When using the line:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=correctusername,password=correctpassword,sec=ntlm,vers=3.0 //192.168.0.9/home /home/pi/data
```

I get the error:

```
mount error(2): No such file or directory
```

I have tried different *sec*s, different *vers*s and different share names. I am not fully sure what share to use but I think it is *home*. The Synology NAS is set to use version 2 to version 3 of SMB.

I can access the drive in the file explorer (Openbox I think) under Go -> Network. After going through two password checks, the address bar shows this: `smb://data.local/home on data.local`

I have tried quite a few things but I don't have much familiarity with Linux. Looks like same problem (unsolved) as here: [mount error(2): No such file or directory - CIFS - Rasperry Pi](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471354/mount-error2-no-such-file-or-directory-cifs-rasperry-pi)

Comment: If it's your NAS, then do you not remember what the share was? If you don't, have you gone into the NAS to verify?

Comment: @NasirRiley I've tried using the names of the Shared Folders in DSM control panel. If that's not right, I don't know wher to find the share name.

Comment: It's your own NAS. Log into it and find out what the share names are. Until then, there's nothing that anyone can do to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. I think the combination of `sec=ntlm,vers=3.0` was causing issue. Running dmesg showed:

```
[ 2938.581371] CIFS VFS: Unable to select appropriate authentication method!
[ 2938.581377] CIFS VFS: \\192.168.0.9 Send error in SessSetup = -22
[ 2938.581408] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
```

I changed to `vers=3.0,sec=ntlmv2` and got `mount error(13): Permission denied` so had to connect with an account that had higher permissions, which wasn't necessary when connecting over Windows or in the file browser, so it's not ideal, but works.

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackExchange! Thanks for taking the time to write up an answer to your own question; sadly, not everyone does this. Please mark your answer as "accepted", so readers can easily spot it.