# Cifs Issues - mount error 2 no such file or directory

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, cifs, nas

I am trying to permanently mount a NAS drive to my raspberry pi (running debian) by adding a line to the file

```
/etc/fstab
```

the line is like this:

```
//192.168.a.real ip/photo/PhotoFrame /home/pi/NAS/photo/PhotoFrame cifs username=jeremy,password=my-real-password,workgroup=WORKGROUP,vers=1.0,users,auto,sec=ntlm,user_xattr 0 0
```

This gives me the error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mount -a
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Comment: Have tried the solutions offered in this page?
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120677/can-not-use-mount-cifs-mount-error2-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 2):

I have run into the same problem and what saved me was the first comment from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111328/cifs-mount-problem
so, check your `ntlm`

explicitly in your case instead of:

```
//192.168.a.real ip/photo/PhotoFrame /home/pi/NAS/photo/PhotoFrame cifs username=jeremy,password=my-real-password,workgroup=WORKGROUP,vers=1.0,users,auto,sec=ntlm,user_xattr 0 0
```

try

```
//192.168.a.real ip/photo/PhotoFrame /home/pi/NAS/photo/PhotoFrame cifs username=jeremy,password=my-real-password,workgroup=WORKGROUP,vers=1.0,users,auto,sec=ntlmv2,user_xattr 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to write it like this

```
//192.168.a.real/ip/photo/PhotoFrame /home/pi/NAS/photo/PhotoFrame cifs username=jeremy,password=my-real-password,workgroup=WORKGROUP,vers=1.0,users,auto,sec=ntlm,user_xattr 0 0
```

(as you have a space between real and ip, not sure if you wanted that?)

and use vers=2.0 at least as 1.0 is deprecated and not safe.