# can not use mount.cifs: mount error(2): No such file or directory w/o password

Tags: mount, cifs

I know there are several topics regarding this however, none of these solve my problem. I've tried the different options mendtioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120677/can-not-use-mount-cifs-mount-error2-no-such-file-or-directory)

I have a router which exposed an attached disk via smb: `\\192.168.1.1\diskname`. No username required. The disk will be mounted at `/mnt/diskname` where the directory exists and has the permissions `777`.

So I run this command

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/diskname /mnt/diskname -o file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,rw,sec=none --verbose
```

which results in

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.1.1,unc=\\192.168.1.1\diskname,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,sec=none,user=root,pass=********
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

```
$ sudo lsmod | grep fuse       
fuse                  131072  5
$ sudo lsmod | grep cifs
cifs                 1077248  0
dns_resolver           16384  1 cifs
fscache               397312  1 cifs
$ mount.cifs --version
mount.cifs version: 6.8
```

Alternatively to `sec=none` I also tried `user=,password=,` which didnt't change the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the only missing part was the `vers=1.0` so when using it as additonal option the mout works. Apparently what it does - according to `man mount.cifs`

```
vers=arg
   SMB protocol version. Allowed values are:
   • 1.0 - The classic CIFS/SMBv1 protocol.
   • 2.0 - The SMBv2.002 protocol. This was initially introduced in Windows Vista Service Pack 1, and Windows Server 2008. Note that the initial release version of Windows Vista spoke a slightly different dialect (2.000) that is not supported.
   • 2.1 - The SMBv2.1 protocol that was introduced in Microsoft Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008R2.
```